# How can I group Client Entities in MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We want to implement a simple hierarchy of Clients and Accounts. Accounts will have only one parent Client (usual functionality) but we want to add parent Clients to Clients, to create a hierarchy:

```
        Client 1----------Act 5
        /      \   
 Client 2      Client 3
 /      \      /      \
Act1   Act2   Act3   Act 4
```

We want the standard screens to show 'rolled up' information, i.e when viewing Client 2, to see the contacts and other associated data from Act 1 and Act 2. When viewing Client 1 we want to see all contacts from all entities in the diagram above.

I think there must a be 'correct' way to do this, using the framework. What is the correct way to implement?

Thank you

Ryan

Comment: Accounts have that hierarchy (it can be the parent of another account). Does this answer the question? I'm not sure to precisely understand what your issue is.

Comment: Yes, thank you. However, if I look at a parent Account, I don't see contacts or activity from sub Accounts. I'd expect to be able to see this data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, but so far as I know, there is no "correct" way to do this using the existing API. The group Dynamics CRM Denver [recently blogged about this](http://dynamicscrmdenver.com/2011/10/21/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-activity-sub-grids-only-display-regarded-records/) and included a response on this topic from Microsoft:

> - This is a key understood limitation of subgrids. The way that rollup
>     is done makes it difficult implement generically and we were not able
>     to get it working for CRM 2011. But fully understand the functional
>     gap this leaves.
> - We are considering this functionality for a future
>     release of CRM.

Because associated (recursive) views only work in supported out-of-box entities, there's no way to make a custom entity that will recursively return all contacts and associated activity under the accounts linked to the custom entity. You'll have to resort to reports and any clever tricks you might come up with (outside the API) to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options here and it all depends on how "integrated" you want this to be.

If you want this to be totally seamless, then I would suggest a plug-in.  A sub-grid with an advanced find view would be the easiest.  Another option is to incorporate an embedded grid with custom fetch and then using JavaScript modify the left nav options.